# Is is possible that a limit on the I/O Usage cause Server Timeout for a PHP script?

Tags: php, io, server, exec, connection-timeout

I am having a very strange Server Timeout error (Error 500) for a process (initiated in a PHP script) that hits the I/O Usage limit of 1MB set by the hosting provider.

Is it possible that this I/O limit actually causes the Timeout error?

Before you ask those are the PHP values I test with:

```
max_execution_time 0
max_input_time -1
```

If not the I/O limit, is there any other server limit that can produce a timeout error?

Usage screenshot [image: attached]